# Book publishing used anti_plagiarism tool

Tags: books

Is all book publishing used plagiarism detection? And can i check plagiarism for old book published from two years and get true percent of similarity?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Most publishers do not *systematically* check for plagiarism. Usually, the book author simply has to assert she or he has all the necessary rights for text and figures - as a part of the contract with the publisher.

In matters of checking an already published book - yes, you may certainly do that. If you find a book is (in part) a plagiarism, you should notify the publisher. To my knowledge, there is *no* "automated" solution to check for supposed plagiarism which yields "valid percentages"... you will have to analyze and compare the text yourself.